# Is there a more efficient way to convert LINQ result to string[] or List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for a way to convert the result of my Linq query to a string[] or List without the usual loop method.  In case you are wondering "Examples are fine, but what are you really trying to do?" I'm trying to do what the example shows; I have a collection of objects and I want a string array or list of the unique IDs that are contained within the list of objects.

I think the code example says it all.  It's a complete program you can run.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    class DataModel
    {
        public DataModel(string id) { ID = id; }
        public string ID;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dummyData = new DataModel[]
        {
            new DataModel("1"),
            new DataModel("1"),
            new DataModel("2"),
            new DataModel("3"),
            new DataModel("3")
        };

        //  This works fine
        var uniqueIDs = 
            from model in dummyData
            group model by model.ID into grouped
            select grouped.Key;

        //  This is the part that bugs me, it's so inelegant...
        List<string> idStringList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var id in uniqueIDs)
            idStringList.Add(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are just looking for `ToList()`:

```
idStringList = uniqueIDs.ToList();
```

If you *just* want the list, you can also add this to the query directly:

```
var idStringList = (from model in dummyData
                    group model by model.ID into grouped
                    select grouped.Key).ToList();
```

Comment: Hard to pick best answer but this one was early and complete - thanks

Comment: @SteveK: `dummyData.Select(m => m.Id).Distinct().ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

```
var list = whatever.ToList();
```

What usual loop method?

Comment: The method I show in my example, that usual method.  I guess usual depends on each person, poor choice of words on my part.  Thanks for the answer, very clean and what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `uniqueIDs.ToList();` This is an extension method on IEnumerable. [Here is the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)

Comment: Because I didn't know it existed ;0)  I missed it somehow, thanks!

Comment: @SteveK Always glad to help :) LINQ really has made a lot of boilerplate code very simple!

Answer (score 2):

You could do the whole operation in one line:

```
List<string> uniqueIDs = dummyData.Select(model => model.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```

the `ToArray()` method works similarly but will provide an array.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous extension methods on IEnumerable you can make use to achieve this like

```
whateverList.ToList()
whateverList.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want an array string[], you can do

```
string[] myArray = (from model in dummyData
                group model by model.ID into grouped
                select grouped.Key.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: @JustinPihony string[] to show that the result is of the correct type and ToString because if you use var, you'll get a int[] or whatever the Key type is. And also not late as no one showed a clear example of an Array (only lists).

Comment: @JustinPihony Thanks for pointing out, I edited. Next time I'll take even more time to reply to double check ;)